# Access printer connected at Virtual Printer Port (USB001) using python-escpos on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, python-escpos

I have created a printing module, which work with printer connected at serial port using `printer.Serial("COM5")` interface provided by python-escpos.

But now, I have to switch to USB printer rather than serial. My USB printer is connected at virtual printer port (USB001). Now, `printer.USB()` requires vendorID and productID but in my case when I see **Device Instance Path**, it does't contain vendorID and productID (screenshot is attached below). I am stuck here that how can I connect with this USB printer.

Please note that my printer is **R290 thermal printer** and I have downloaded its driver from http://itambition.com/printer.html. The printer is connected at USB001 and test page is being printed successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue using following steps:

- connect USB printer
- install R290 driver from http://itambition.com/printer.html. it will
  setup USB001 for usb printer
- from printer & scanners menu, select printer properties and share the
  printer
- open cmd as administrator and run:

> net use lpt1    \your-systems-hostname\printer-sharename

- now connect printer.File("LPT1") interface of python-escpos and start
  printing